# cant install react-navigation using npm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, react-native, npm

i cant install react-navigation using
`npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`

and this will not install, this returns errors like this(on macbook pro with m1 chip):

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from react-native-reanimated@2.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-reanimated
npm ERR!     react-native-reanimated@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"17.0.1" from react-native@0.64.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from react-native-reanimated@2.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-reanimated
npm ERR!     react-native-reanimated@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/myuser/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report. /*i cant found this file*/

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myuser/.npm/_logs/2021-03-29T16_41_09_547Z-debug.log
```

What should i doing ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. But now i have different error when i run "pod install" command. What can i do ? This is error:

Comment: Auto-linking React Native modules for target `App3`: RNCMaskedView, RNGestureHandler, RNReanimated, RNScreens, ReactNativeNavigation, and react-native-safe-area-context
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactNativeNavigation":
  In Podfile:
    ReactNativeNavigation (from `../node_modules/react-native-navigation`)

Specs satisfying the `ReactNativeNavigation (from `../node_modules/react-native-navigation`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.